# data over which hash is calculated in digital certificate?

Tags: security, digital-certificate

I create a self signed certificate using BP cryptography tool now I want to verify its signature manually without using openssl.
Can anyone give me the example of a self signed certificate and how to calculate the signature of certificate?

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you are talking about X.509 certificates, not e.g. some flavour of CV certificates.*

According to [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) *Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile*:

> ### [4.1.  Basic Certificate Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1)

> The X.509 v3 certificate basic syntax is as follows.  For signature
> calculation, the data that is to be signed is encoded using the ASN.1
> distinguished encoding rules (DER) [X.690].  ASN.1 DER encoding is a
> tag, length, value encoding system for each element.

> ```
> Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
> ```

```
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }
```

> ```
> TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
> ```

```
    version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
    serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
    signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    issuer               Name,
    validity             Validity,
    subject              Name,
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                         -- If present, version MUST be v3
    }
```

> ```
> ...
> ```

> ```
> SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
> ```

```
    algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

Concerning your task:

> I want to verify its signature manually

All you have to do is use an ASN.1 parser to get the three top level elements of the certificate (the to-be-signed certificate part `tbsCertificate`, the algorithm identifier `signatureAlgorithm`, and the signature bytes `signatureValue`) and check, whether the signature value indeed signs the tbsCertificate.

As your certificate is self-signed, you have to check against the `subjectPublicKey` inside the `tbsCertificate`.